# Sending Timezone within API call

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api, mobilepush

I'm implementing some API calls to the MobilePush SDK using postman. Right now I'm facing a timezone (I think) misinterpretation, as each time I schedule a Push Message, I need to do it based on a different timezone. Example:

```
{
    "InclusionListIds": [
        "------dmVmxFZXVqRGtqZk53N1lVUT------"
    ],
    "Override": true,
    "MessageText": "New information available",
    "title": "Boost your winnings!",
    "subtitle": "Check your app to see what else is in store.",
    "mutable-content": 1,
    "SendTime": "2021-08-23 15:00"
}
```

As you can see, message was schedule to be delivered today at 15:00 hours. However, it will arrive at 16:00.

I was checking the documentation (https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-apis.meta/mc-apis/postMessageList.htm) but there's no info about scheduling a message and forcing its timezone. I also tried adding it in the following ways:

```
"SendTime": "2021-08-23T15:00:00.000-05:00",
"SendTime": "2021-08-23 15:00 -05:00"
"SendTime": "2021-08-23 15:00-05:00"
"SendTime": "2021-08-23T15:00-05:00"
```

However, I got the following error:

```
{
    "errors": [
        "2021-08-23T15:38:00.000-05:00 is not a valid send time (yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm)."
    ]
}
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: All Salesforce REST (and other) APIs always work in UTC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2021-08-23T15:38:00.000Z <- That is the format you're looking for.  All date-times are UTC.

Comment: Thanks, @Bill Mote but there's a way to force a specific timezone? let's say, GMT-03?

Comment: Convert your times and use UTC.  It's the only foolproof way of ensuring what you want is executed appropriately.